# computing proportions in R and plotting them, correcting code mistakes

Tags: r, statistics, statistics-bootstrap, proportions

```
df$age = as.numeric(df$age)

 library(dplyr)
 df%>%
   group_by(level) %>%
   summarise(mean_age = mean(age), na.rm = TRUE)
```

As i got an NA on N7 that i couldn't seem to get rid of, i tried something else :

```
 df_mean <- aggregate(x = df$age,
          by = list(df$level),
          FUN = mean,
          na.rm = TRUE)

colnames(df_mean) = c("level", "age")
df_mean <- df_mean[-1,]
```

I would like to plot this dataframe, to show the potential link between level and age
For instance, i tried the very basic following plot :

```
 attach(df_mean)
 age =round(age, digits = 2)
 sort(level) # to check that it would sort them in the right way when plotting
 plot(age ~ level)
```

It doesn't work as level isn't a numeric variable

I would like to plot it in a smart way, does anyone have any ideas ?

```
ggplot(data = df_mean) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = level, y = age))

ggplot(data = df) +
   geom_point(mapping = aes(x = level, y = age))


ggplot(df, aes(level, age)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~sex)
```

Here i would like to remove the plot with (NA), although it shows there is an NA value on N7

The above codes work, and shows clearly that the mean age in N7 is way lower than in others :  ut perhaps explains the NA i had when trying to compute the mean before. Does anyone have an idea of how  could run some test to see where the anomaly lies ?

I then try to compute the proportion of women in each level, using the following code :

```
df %>%
  group_by(level) %>%
  transmute(proportion_of_women <- sex == F) %>%
  summarise(prop_women == means(proportion_of_women = T))
```

Seeing it does not work, i tried something else :

```
df%>%
  select(level, sex)%>%
  group_by(level)%>%
  prop.table(sex == "F", margin = 1) # pass the margin argument in the proportion call, else R will compute the proportion over the whole sample and not group by group
```

It did not work either.
I tried a last one, which then works. But im concerned that this time i have no NAs in N7, contrary to my attempt to compute the mean age per level.

```
df%>%
  select(level, sex)%>%
  group_by(level)%>%
  summarise(mean = mean(sex == "F"))
```

It seems to work.
Finally, i would like plot this distribution (proportion of men/women in each level),
but do not know how to proceed. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Here is my dataset :

```r
structure(list(sex = c("F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", 
"F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", 
"H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", 
"F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", 
"H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "F", 
"H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", 
"F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", 
"H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", 
"H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", 
"F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "F", 
"H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", 
"H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", 
"F", "H", "H", "#N/A", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", 
"F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", 
"H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", 
"H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", 
"F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", 
"F", "F", "H", "F", "H", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", 
"H", "F", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H"), age = c("24", "33", "53", "32", "38", "21", "45", 
"51", "40", "40", "61", "61", "44", "31", "33", "55", "42", "37", 
"62", "30", "53", "39", "29", "21", "53", "30", "61", "39", "30", 
"38", "40", "34", "24", "36", "34", "34", "49", "25", "48", "25", 
"54", "33", "57", "51", "35", "62", "39", "24", "35", "41", "30", 
"55", "28", "48", "48", "61", "41", "36", "53", "40", "40", "31", 
"31", "30", "33", "31", "42", "41", "40", "47", "46", "38", "27", 
"60", "40", "52", "45", "54", "52", "28", "41", "32", "35", "39", 
"48", "32", "46", "30", "55", "27", "33", "47", "59", "38", "49", 
"53", "42", "41", "33", "34", "41", "54", "38", "55", "50", "54", 
"53", "43", "38", "40", "28", "42", "43", "37", "52", "62", "60", 
"52", "42", "53", "22", "30", "40", "35", "37", "39", "60", "27", 
"34", "33", "49", "67", "22", "29", "42", "26", "36", "26", "25", 
"49", "43", "38", "61", "56", "54", "36", "27", "31", "60", "47", 
"28", "44", "55", "53", "37", "36", "39", "31", "47", "38", "29", 
"35", "44", "36", "35", "37", "42", "29", "36", "41", "27", "40", 
"31", "48", "27", "40", "54", "32", "62", "31", "57", "56", "47", 
"44", "46", "40", "26", "35", "33", "29", "30", "23", "53", "39", 
"52", "46", "22", "39", "53", "55", "23", "25", "39", "26", "35", 
"56", "32", "31", "31", "47", "27", "32", "34", "35", "44", "29", 
"39", "42", "50", "21", "37", "46", "40", "45", "60", "28", "64", 
"37", "42", "28", "54", "40", "35", "39", "57", "46", "29", "52", 
"42", "52", "57", "44", "31", "23", "51", "33", "39", "38", "28", 
"40", "48", "54", "53", "28", "47", "51", "54", "35", "27", "32", 
"33", "48", "24", "39", "26", "43", "24", "56", "38", "27", "53", 
"36", "50", "42", "59", "52", "25", "31", "33", "29", "39", "45", 
"46", "37", "44", "32", "63", "30", "34", "34", "27", "47", "27", 
"51", "56", "39", "51", "37", "56", "49", "54", "59", "38", "29", 
"42", "57", "30", "37", "47", "35", NA, "56", "30", "47", "25", 
"52", "50", "51", "42", "43", "22", "20", "26", "37", "42", "31", 
"45", "43", "38", "23", "42", "48", "32", "51", "53", "55", "28", 
"49", "54", "26", "35", "43", "54", "63", "60", "46", "39", "29", 
"27", "43", "32", "47", "28", "37", "31", "21", "32", "46", "57", 
"56", "50", "22", "38", "28", "29", "47", "36", "44", "24", "38", 
"33", "31", "42", "45", "26", "31", "47", "37", "34", "46", "34", 
"41", "21", "50", "31", "52", "38", "54", "42", "48", "26", "32", 
"28", "52", "33", "30", "61", "58", "56", "49", "29", "33", "45", 
"41", "44", "34", "62", "48", "38", "57", "59", "36", "51", "21", 
"39", "41", "56", "34", "39", "36", "42", "33", "32", "59", "45", 
"23", "28", "43", "45", "52", "58", "31", "60", "50", "45", "43", 
"46", "47", "55", "29", "24", "39", "39", "35", "50", "50", "47", 
"46", "50", "52", "42", "24", "40", "44", "32", "35", "43", "43", 
"30", "43", "37", "27", "45", "48", "32", "30", "37", "23", "41", 
"30", "51", "43", "36", "34", "44", "22", "40", "51", "39", "32", 
"52", "33", "44", "35", "57", "38", "51", "56", "40", "50", "52", 
"46", "40", "26", "53", "53", "26", "44", "22", "58", "52", "31", 
"57", "51", "49", "45", "28", "53", "58", "34", "45", "29", "45", 
"51", "32", "37", "35", "44", "45", "29", "42", "35", "23", "47", 
"32", "50", "43", "44", "41", "55", "55", "62", "41", "33", "42", 
"50", "40", "33", "35", "29", "45", "29", "32", "58", "46", "40", 
"36", "37", "39", "46", "28", "56", "44", "31", "41", "43", "34", 
"48", "30", "52", "25", "35", "43", "53", "55", "34", "44", "50"
), time_passed = c("0", "3", "4", "0", "2", "0", "8", "20", "5", 
"0", "27", "28", "17", "4", "0", "20", "4", "0", "31", "2", "24", 
"5", "3", "1", "23", "0", "22", "3", "6", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"14", "0", "11", "24", "1", "8", "0", "8", "3", "29", "26", "9", 
"37", "8", "0", "10", "6", "0", "30", "2", "11", "24", "38", 
"8", "0", "27", "4", "3", "4", "5", "5", "0", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "23", "1", "1", "1", "5", "8", "2", "0", "29", "2", "6", 
"1", "1", "8", "1", "15", "0", "14", "3", "23", "4", "2", "23", 
"13", "11", "4", "19", "3", "3", "9", "7", "5", "7", "5", "12", 
"28", "25", "21", "2", "0", "0", "1", "1", "3", "6", "8", "31", 
"38", "25", "18", "28", "0", "7", "17", "11", "4", "6", "30", 
"0", "5", "3", "7", "3", "0", "4", "21", "2", "12", "0", "0", 
"19", "4", "4", "33", "35", "23", "3", "4", "2", "38", "22", 
"2", "2", "28", "4", "1", "5", "0", "6", "14", "4", "1", "5", 
"21", "4", "6", "6", "10", "0", "1", "4", "3", "1", "1", "18", 
"0", "4", "26", "0", "29", "0", "22", "18", "24", "6", "2", "0", 
"4", "4", "9", "3", "6", "1", "29", "5", "17", "6", "0", "13", 
"22", "33", "0", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "9", "17", 
"2", "7", "4", "4", "6", "0", "5", "4", "25", "1", "3", "1", 
"11", "3", "38", "0", "39", "4", "1", "5", "30", "5", "0", "0", 
"16", "7", "7", "21", "23", "2", "6", "21", "5", "0", "1", "7", 
"2", "1", "1", "10", "3", "0", "19", "0", "20", "25", "28", "7", 
"3", "3", "10", "8", "0", "1", "2", "1", "0", "4", "10", "1", 
"20", "1", "23", "6", "38", "3", "4", "5", "0", "4", "1", "3", 
"24", "8", "23", "4", "23", "5", "0", "8", "1", "23", "1", "0", 
"3", "4", "30", "13", "23", "2", "28", "18", "1", "4", "5", "32", 
"1", "4", "4", "13", "#N/A", "27", "1", "15", "0", "30", "18", 
"5", "4", "0", "1", "0", "2", "3", "4", "0", "3", "18", "5", 
"0", "5", "0", "2", "5", "26", "27", "1", "10", "3", "0", "1", 
"17", "25", "25", "23", "1", "3", "0", "3", "8", "7", "0", "0", 
"10", "8", "0", "0", "16", "28", "1", "0", "1", "6", "4", "1", 
"8", "12", "5", "0", "5", "1", "2", "6", "7", "2", "0", "23", 
"0", "4", "20", "8", "6", "1", "1", "2", "7", "8", "32", "20", 
"1", "0", "7", "5", "13", "0", "3", "0", "25", "24", "24", "4", 
"4", "6", "4", "7", "2", "22", "11", "6", "23", "21", "5", "29", 
"0", "7", "2", "31", "4", "6", "9", "9", "3", "4", "31", "3", 
"0", "4", "1", "10", "29", "20", "1", "33", "4", "9", "3", "13", 
"4", "29", "8", "0", "6", "2", "12", "21", "25", "21", "6", "0", 
"21", "13", "0", "1", "13", "7", "4", "17", "9", "3", "5", "4", 
"2", "3", "23", "1", "5", "6", "0", "4", "3", "6", "1", "1", 
"10", "7", "1", "9", "21", "10", "5", "29", "0", "7", "2", "24", 
"3", "23", "23", "17", "7", "2", "13", "13", "1", "19", "2", 
"0", "4", "1", "31", "19", "5", "26", "22", "3", "22", "4", "30", 
"14", "3", "5", "2", "4", "26", "10", "5", "12", "17", "21", 
"7", "7", "2", "0", "24", "0", "24", "19", "1", "6", "29", "30", 
"33", "18", "0", "18", "2", "5", "3", "10", "1", "7", "2", "2", 
"38", "3", "15", "9", "10", "7", "18", "3", "5", "13", "4", "4", 
"10", "13", "1", "1", "28", "2", "2", "19", "0", "23", "1", "7", 
"0"), level = c("N7  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "    ", 
"N7  ", "N9  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N9  ", "N5  ", "N5  ", 
"N7  ", "N8  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N6  ", 
"N7  ", "    ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", 
"N8  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", 
"N9  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", 
"N6  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N6  ", 
"N5  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", 
"N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N4  ", "N9  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", 
"N8  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", 
"N6  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N8  ", 
"N8  ", "N8  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", 
"N4  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N1  ", "N5  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N9  ", "N4  ", "N4  ", 
"N8  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N5  ", 
"N9  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "    ", "N4  ", 
"N4  ", "N7  ", "N3  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N2  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N3  ", "N8  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", 
"N3  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N3  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N1  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N1  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", 
"N8  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N2  ", 
"N7  ", "    ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N4  ", "N3  ", 
"N9  ", "N8  ", "N1  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N5  ", "N3  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N5  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N5  ", "N2  ", 
"N6  ", "N5  ", "N9  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "N6  ", 
"N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", 
"N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", 
"N9  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", 
"N4  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N5  ", "N2  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", 
"N8  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", 
"N9  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N3  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "    ", "N9  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N5  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", 
"N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "    ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", 
"N8  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N1  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", 
"N4  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "    ", "N8  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", 
"N4  ", "N5  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", 
"N8  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", 
"N4  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "    ", "N7  ", "N9  ", 
"    ", "N9  ", "N9  ", "    ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N6  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N5  ", "N9  ", 
"N2  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", 
"N4  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "    ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "    ", "N7  ", 
"N5  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N9  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N4  ", 
"N7  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", 
"N7  ", "N5  ", "N9  ", "N3  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", 
"N8  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N5  ", "N4  ", 
"N5  ", "N6  ", "N5  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", 
"N7  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N8  ", 
"N4  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N9  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "    ", "N8  ", "N7  ", 
"N9  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N1  ", "N7  ", "N3  ", 
"N7  ", "N4  ", "    ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", 
"N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N3  ", "N7  ", 
"N5  ", "N8  ", "N4  ", "N8  ", "    ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N5  ", 
"N8  ", "N8  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N6  ", "N4  ", 
"N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", 
"N5  ", "N2  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "    ", "N9  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", 
"N5  ", "N8  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N4  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N4  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", 
"N4  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N6  ", "N7  ", 
"N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N7  ", "N5  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", 
"N8  ", "N9  "), wage = c("2 605,00", "4 931,00", "11 123,00", 
"3 750,00", "6 180,00", "858,31", "5 092,00", "9 276,00", "8 611,00", 
"4 500,00", "3 693,00", "11 489,00", "2 896,00", "2 220,00", 
"5 000,00", "5 398,00", "6 923,00", "3 800,00", "9 615,00", "3 448,00", 
"5 568,00", "675,00", "2 906,00", "1 255,67", "4 177,00", "4 300,00", 
"4 200,00", "5 389,00", "2 205,00", "6 600,00", "5 700,00", "5 400,00", 
"2 610,00", "2 679,00", "2 600,00", "2 893,00", "3 742,00", "2 605,00", 
"4 835,00", "2 700,00", "7 533,00", "3 764,00", "3 074,00", "3 499,00", 
"4 075,00", "6 613,00", "12 785,00", "2 050,00", "3 550,00", 
"3 687,00", "2 700,00", "3 075,00", "2 688,00", "5 385,00", "3 225,00", 
"2 231,00", "3 872,00", "3 385,00", "4 075,00", "3 500,00", "6 679,00", 
"2 720,00", "2 497,00", "2 822,00", "2 400,00", "3 900,00", "3 400,00", 
"7 600,00", "4 600,00", "5 735,00", "5 000,00", "3 605,00", "2 650,00", 
"1 246,00", "2 543,00", "9 903,00", "6 400,00", "4 604,00", "6 510,00", 
"2 315,00", "6 600,00", "3 900,00", "4 198,00", "4 100,00", "4 129,00", 
"4 080,00", "3 623,00", "3 117,00", "4 298,00", "2 650,00", "4 362,00", 
"3 332,00", "10 000,00", "5 080,00", "5 438,00", "6 830,00", 
"2 866,00", "4 395,00", "2 443,00", "4 311,00", "4 759,00", "6 917,00", 
"2 386,00", "4 289,00", "3 350,00", "1 905,00", "2 858,00", "3 100,00", 
"5 600,00", "2 000,00", "2 900,00", "4 000,00", "6 966,00", "3 432,00", 
"23 888,00", "8 606,00", "1 881,00", "2 258,00", "4 403,00", 
"5 923,00", "2 605,00", "2 341,00", "2 854,00", "4 670,00", "5 056,00", 
"2 491,00", "8 434,00", "4 000,00", "4 583,00", "2 330,00", "6 063,00", 
"3 924,00", "1 271,58", "2 164,00", "2 249,00", "2 657,00", "2 449,00", 
"2 800,00", "3 448,00", "2 379,00", "6 941,00", "5 768,00", "3 913,00", 
"3 977,00", "4 067,00", "4 000,00", "2 773,00", "2 956,00", "2 569,00", 
"5 532,00", "2 868,00", "4 488,00", "6 162,00", "2 727,00", "4 650,00", 
"2 614,00", "6 000,00", "3 392,00", "2 411,00", "2 403,20", "3 090,00", 
"3 002,00", "2 594,00", "2 896,00", "2 862,40", "2 777,00", "2 230,00", 
"1 935,00", "4 750,00", "8 532,00", "2 128,00", "4 300,00", "3 000,00", 
"4 164,00", "2 605,00", "2 892,00", "8 623,00", "3 100,00", "2 729,00", 
"3 850,00", "3 855,00", "5 160,00", "5 232,00", "6 213,00", "4 707,00", 
"4 300,00", "2 408,00", "2 343,00", "2 624,00", "1 894,00", "3 255,00", 
"969,57", "3 291,54", "2 820,00", "4 322,00", "2 159,00", "2 000,00", 
"2 427,00", "11 615,00", "5 555,00", "1 323,94", "2 448,00", 
"5 200,00", "2 901,00", "3 904,00", "9 338,00", "3 881,00", "3 536,00", 
"2 504,00", "5 202,00", "3 098,00", "2 936,00", "3 962,00", "4 692,00", 
"5 676,00", "2 650,00", "3 511,00", "2 766,00", "3 018,00", "1 900,00", 
"5 230,00", "4 100,00", "4 806,00", "2 700,00", "2 686,00", "2 605,00", 
"10 860,00", "2 942,00", "4 900,00", "2 963,00", "3 581,00", 
"6 613,00", "4 800,00", "5 231,00", "8 150,00", "2 429,00", "2 371,00", 
"2 461,00", "3 247,00", "2 480,00", "10 626,00", "5 702,00", 
"2 476,00", "2 200,00", "6 750,00", "2 776,00", "5 600,00", "3 700,00", 
"2 775,00", "2 780,00", "5 555,00", "11 600,00", "5 154,00", 
"3 300,00", "3 466,00", "3 362,00", "5 509,00", "3 700,00", "2 319,00", 
"2 918,00", "2 912,00", "11 194,00", "2 610,00", "5 670,00", 
"2 605,00", "4 515,00", "2 000,00", "8 409,00", "2 945,00", "2 533,00", 
"9 629,00", "3 850,00", "2 127,00", "6 200,00", "3 719,00", "12 276,00", 
"2 159,00", "3 432,00", "2 350,00", "2 529,00", "4 500,00", "7 272,00", 
"2 798,00", "2 379,00", "2 718,00", "4 431,00", "6 410,00", "3 229,00", 
"2 350,00", "3 415,00", "2 700,00", "3 182,00", "2 800,00", "5 900,00", 
"14 373,00", "2 165,00", "3 417,00", "2 462,00", "7 029,00", 
"6 500,00", "17 696,00", "8 730,00", "4 500,00", "2 851,00", 
"4 710,00", "3 169,00", "2 380,00", "3 479,00", "6 492,00", "2 438,00", 
"", "8 881,00", "3 000,00", "5 500,00", "1 230,49", "2 804,00", 
"4 427,00", "8 161,00", "9 576,00", "4 738,00", "2 026,00", "699,37", 
"2 000,00", "5 166,00", "2 858,00", "4 100,00", "2 593,00", "3 647,00", 
"3 561,00", "985,47", "4 699,00", "2 300,00", "3 230,00", "10 710,00", 
"3 700,00", "3 551,00", "2 209,00", "5 654,00", "11 539,00", 
"3 150,00", "3 600,00", "2 775,00", "4 939,00", "5 506,00", "4 235,00", 
"6 500,00", "2 291,00", "2 450,00", "2 835,00", "2 661,00", "2 457,00", 
"5 700,00", "2 000,00", "3 101,00", "2 374,00", "1 353,60", "3 650,00", 
"11 466,00", "14 200,00", "12 000,00", "12 650,00", "985,47", 
"6 987,00", "2 768,00", "3 800,00", "4 406,00", "2 882,00", "4 760,00", 
"1 952,00", "2 577,00", "2 958,00", "2 289,00", "2 912,00", "12 924,00", 
"1 911,00", "4 100,00", "5 069,00", "3 600,00", "1 569,00", "6 891,00", 
"1 840,00", "3 278,00", "1 969,00", "13 077,00", "2 650,00", 
"24 577,00", "3 205,00", "4 165,00", "2 899,00", "5 006,00", 
"2 700,00", "3 612,00", "2 183,00", "5 366,00", "3 000,00", "2 950,00", 
"26 667,00", "5 699,00", "3 607,00", "7 292,00", "3 350,00", 
"3 213,00", "4 586,00", "4 838,00", "5 077,00", "3 908,00", "10 300,00", 
"7 398,00", "3 916,00", "3 373,00", "7 113,00", "4 150,00", "3 476,00", 
"1 935,00", "3 217,00", "2 660,00", "6 816,00", "2 928,00", "6 300,00", 
"2 912,00", "3 587,00", "2 390,00", "4 260,00", "3 264,00", "20 290,00", 
"1 255,68", "2 854,00", "3 800,00", "2 835,00", "4 296,00", "6 000,00", 
"3 000,00", "6 954,00", "4 090,00", "5 605,00", "5 689,00", "2 838,00", 
"2 567,00", "3 055,00", "2 821,00", "2 300,00", "3 052,00", "4 400,00", 
"2 636,00", "5 953,00", "2 028,00", "3 861,00", "5 847,00", "6 800,00", 
"4 517,00", "4 341,00", "2 605,00", "9 300,00", "7 403,00", "2 292,00", 
"4 011,00", "3 280,00", "2 736,00", "4 002,00", "5 009,00", "4 697,00", 
"2 714,00", "8 716,00", "6 179,00", "7 700,00", "2 935,00", "4 236,00", 
"1 255,68", "5 252,00", "2 768,00", "8 314,00", "5 000,00", "4 000,00", 
"2 843,00", "4 428,00", "1 351,04", "5 014,00", "2 612,00", "3 003,00", 
"2 291,00", "20 258,00", "2 800,00", "5 128,00", "4 900,00", 
"6 611,00", "5 150,00", "3 516,00", "3 135,00", "4 037,00", "3 440,00", 
"4 920,00", "9 051,00", "2 414,00", "2 610,00", "2 905,00", "6 000,00", 
"2 001,00", "4 473,00", "1 351,04", "5 266,00", "6 863,00", "1 877,00", 
"6 010,00", "6 900,00", "4 369,00", "3 697,00", "3 005,00", "3 382,00", 
"3 473,00", "2 353,00", "3 925,00", "2 809,00", "4 240,00", "3 255,00", 
"2 424,00", "4 349,00", "2 770,00", "3 385,00", "2 776,00", "2 057,00", 
"2 734,00", "3 604,00", "1 351,05", "7 338,00", "2 600,00", "5 698,00", 
"2 945,00", "4 725,00", "2 792,00", "4 356,00", "2 970,00", "7 041,00", 
"4 030,00", "4 600,00", "4 294,00", "2 511,00", "2 422,00", "4 931,00", 
"4 003,00", "3 100,00", "2 860,00", "3 300,00", "3 500,00", "2 780,00", 
"5 872,00", "3 041,00", "3 873,00", "2 871,00", "3 109,00", "2 943,00", 
"2 091,00", "7 219,00", "3 061,60", "3 374,00", "4 049,00", "4 943,00", 
"2 745,00", "5 540,00", "4 350,00", "7 670,00", "2 735,00", "4 650,00", 
"2 959,00", "4 620,00", "9 807,00", "5 460,00", "4 396,00", "10 770,00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -568L))
```

Comment: Side-question: what tutorial are you following? The use of `attach` is so discouraged that I've not seen any "recent" tutorial actually recommend it, and you're asking it in the same question as using `dplyr` code, which is rather counter to `attach` and its limited utility. If you haven't heard it before, the use of `attach` promotes bad habits and difficult-to-troubleshoot issues; if you're going to be using R for more than a week, I suggest you learn to not use it. (And if you _must_, then ... use `detach` everywhere you use `attach, they should always be perfectly and closely paired.

Comment: i am currently "learning by doing", thus it's mostly youtube videos and stack overflow answers that get me going. Thanks for the advice, i won't use attach() anymore !

Answer (score 0):

Below are a few hints that may help you explore your data:

1. clean up your data; code the unknown values as NA
2. transform your data into suitable classes, e.g. numeric values for age, sex (will automatically transform "NA" character into (numeric) NA), factors for sex and level
3. you can use an ordered factor for level
4. you may try to run a regression model to see whether any of the variables in df are associated; see for example https://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-ordered-factors-in-a-linear-model/

Below is a quick example:

```r
# input data
   sex=c("F","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","H","H","H","H","H","F","F","F","F","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","F","H","F","H","F","H","F","H","F","F","F","F","F","F","H","H","F","H","F","H","F","F","H","H","F","H","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","F","F","H","H","H","F","H","F","F","H","F","F","F","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","H","F","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","H","H","F","H","F","H","F","F","H","F","F","F","H","H","F","H","F","H","F","F","F","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","F","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","F","H","F","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","F","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","F","F","H","F","F","H","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","H","F","H","F","F","H","H","H","H","F","F","H","H","H","F","F","F","F","F","H","F","F","F","H","H","F","H","H","F","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","F","H","H","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","F","F","H","H","H","H","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","H","H","F","H","F","H","H","H","H","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","H","H","H","H","F","F","F","H","H","NA","H","F","H","H","H","F","F","F","F","H","H","H","F","H","H","F","F","F","H","H","H","F","F","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","F","F","F","F","H","F","H","F","F","H","H","H","F","H","H","F","H","F","F","F","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","F","H","F","F","F","H","F","H","F","H","H","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","F","H","H","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","H","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","H","H","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","F","H","H","H","F","F","H","F","F","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","H","F","H","H","H","H","F","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","F","F","F","H","F","F","H","F","F","H","H","H","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","H","F","F","F","H","H","F","H","H","H","F","H","F","F","F","F","H","H","F","F","H","F","H","F","H","F","F","F","F","H","H","F","F","F","F","F","H","F","H","H","F","F","F","F","H","F","F","H","F","H","F","F","F","F","F","F","H","H","H","F","H","F","H","H","H","F","H","H","H","H","H","H","H")
    
    age=c("24","33","53","32","38","21","45","51","40","40","61","61","44","31","33","55","42","37","62","30","53","39","29","21","53","30","61","39","30","38","40","34","24","36","34","34","49","25","48","25","54","33","57","51","35","62","39","24","35","41","30","55","28","48","48","61","41","36","53","40","40","31","31","30","33","31","42","41","40","47","46","38","27","60","40","52","45","54","52","28","41","32","35","39","48","32","46","30","55","27","33","47","59","38","49","53","42","41","33","34","41","54","38","55","50","54","53","43","38","40","28","42","43","37","52","62","60","52","42","53","22","30","40","35","37","39","60","27","34","33","49","67","22","29","42","26","36","26","25","49","43","38","61","56","54","36","27","31","60","47","28","44","55","53","37","36","39","31","47","38","29","35","44","36","35","37","42","29","36","41","27","40","31","48","27","40","54","32","62","31","57","56","47","44","46","40","26","35","33","29","30","23","53","39","52","46","22","39","53","55","23","25","39","26","35","56","32","31","31","47","27","32","34","35","44","29","39","42","50","21","37","46","40","45","60","28","64","37","42","28","54","40","35","39","57","46","29","52","42","52","57","44","31","23","51","33","39","38","28","40","48","54","53","28","47","51","54","35","27","32","33","48","24","39","26","43","24","56","38","27","53","36","50","42","59","52","25","31","33","29","39","45","46","37","44","32","63","30","34","34","27","47","27","51","56","39","51","37","56","49","54","59","38","29","42","57","30","37","47","35","NA","56","30","47","25","52","50","51","42","43","22","20","26","37","42","31","45","43","38","23","42","48","32","51","53","55","28","49","54","26","35","43","54","63","60","46","39","29","27","43","32","47","28","37","31","21","32","46","57","56","50","22","38","28","29","47","36","44","24","38","33","31","42","45","26","31","47","37","34","46","34","41","21","50","31","52","38","54","42","48","26","32","28","52","33","30","61","58","56","49","29","33","45","41","44","34","62","48","38","57","59","36","51","21","39","41","56","34","39","36","42","33","32","59","45","23","28","43","45","52","58","31","60","50","45","43","46","47","55","29","24","39","39","35","50","50","47","46","50","52","42","24","40","44","32","35","43","43","30","43","37","27","45","48","32","30","37","23","41","30","51","43","36","34","44","22","40","51","39","32","52","33","44","35","57","38","51","56","40","50","52","46","40","26","53","53","26","44","22","58","52","31","57","51","49","45","28","53","58","34","45","29","45","51","32","37","35","44","45","29","42","35","23","47","32","50","43","44","41","55","55","62","41","33","42","50","40","33","35","29","45","29","32","58","46","40","36","37","39","46","28","56","44","31","41","43","34","48","30","52","25","35","43","53","55","34","44","50")
    
    time_passed=c("0","3","4","0","2","0","8","20","5","0","27","28","17","4","0","20","4","0","31","2","24","5","3","1","23","0","22","3","6","1","0","0","0","14","0","11","24","1","8","0","8","3","29","26","9","37","8","0","10","6","0","30","2","11","24","38","8","0","27","4","3","4","5","5","0","2","1","2","1","23","1","1","1","5","8","2","0","29","2","6","1","1","8","1","15","0","14","3","23","4","2","23","13","11","4","19","3","3","9","7","5","7","5","12","28","25","21","2","0","0","1","1","3","6","8","31","38","25","18","28","0","7","17","11","4","6","30","0","5","3","7","3","0","4","21","2","12","0","0","19","4","4","33","35","23","3","4","2","38","22","2","2","28","4","1","5","0","6","14","4","1","5","21","4","6","6","10","0","1","4","3","1","1","18","0","4","26","0","29","0","22","18","24","6","2","0","4","4","9","3","6","1","29","5","17","6","0","13","22","33","0","2","2","3","3","4","4","2","9","17","2","7","4","4","6","0","5","4","25","1","3","1","11","3","38","0","39","4","1","5","30","5","0","0","16","7","7","21","23","2","6","21","5","0","1","7","2","1","1","10","3","0","19","0","20","25","28","7","3","3","10","8","0","1","2","1","0","4","10","1","20","1","23","6","38","3","4","5","0","4","1","3","24","8","23","4","23","5","0","8","1","23","1","0","3","4","30","13","23","2","28","18","1","4","5","32","1","4","4","13","NA","27","1","15","0","30","18","5","4","0","1","0","2","3","4","0","3","18","5","0","5","0","2","5","26","27","1","10","3","0","1","17","25","25","23","1","3","0","3","8","7","0","0","10","8","0","0","16","28","1","0","1","6","4","1","8","12","5","0","5","1","2","6","7","2","0","23","0","4","20","8","6","1","1","2","7","8","32","20","1","0","7","5","13","0","3","0","25","24","24","4","4","6","4","7","2","22","11","6","23","21","5","29","0","7","2","31","4","6","9","9","3","4","31","3","0","4","1","10","29","20","1","33","4","9","3","13","4","29","8","0","6","2","12","21","25","21","6","0","21","13","0","1","13","7","4","17","9","3","5","4","2","3","23","1","5","6","0","4","3","6","1","1","10","7","1","9","21","10","5","29","0","7","2","24","3","23","23","17","7","2","13","13","1","19","2","0","4","1","31","19","5","26","22","3","22","4","30","14","3","5","2","4","26","10","5","12","17","21","7","7","2","0","24","0","24","19","1","6","29","30","33","18","0","18","2","5","3","10","1","7","2","2","38","3","15","9","10","7","18","3","5","13","4","4","10","13","1","1","28","2","2","19","0","23","1","7","0")
    
    level=c("N7","N7","N9","N7","N8","","N7","N9","N9","N7","N5","N9","N5","N5","N7","N8","N9","N7","N9","N7","N8","N6","N7","","N7","N7","N6","N7","N4","N8","N8","N8","N7","N5","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N8","N7","N4","N7","N7","N8","N9","N4","N7","N7","N7","N5","N7","N8","N6","N5","N7","N7","N7","N7","N8","N6","N5","N7","N5","N7","N7","N8","N7","N8","N8","N7","N7","N5","N4","N9","N8","N7","N8","N4","N7","N7","N8","N7","N6","N7","N6","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N9","N8","N8","N8","N5","N8","N4","N7","N8","N8","N4","N7","N6","N1","N5","N5","N8","N4","N7","N7","N8","N7","N9","N9","N4","N4","N8","N8","N7","N4","N5","N8","N8","N5","N9","N7","N7","N4","N8","N8","","N4","N4","N7","N3","N7","N7","N2","N8","N8","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N3","N8","N7","N7","N8","N4","N7","N5","N8","N7","N3","N7","N7","N7","N3","N7","N7","N7","N1","N4","N7","N9","N4","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N9","N7","N1","N7","N6","N7","N8","N8","N7","N7","N5","N7","N5","N2","N7","","N7","N7","N7","N4","N4","N3","N9","N8","N1","N5","N7","N7","N7","N9","N7","N7","N5","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N5","N5","N3","N7","N7","N7","N5","N5","N7","N9","N5","N7","N7","N7","N8","N8","N8","N8","N4","N5","N2","N6","N5","N9","N8","N4","N4","N8","N6","N8","N7","N7","N5","N7","N9","N8","N7","N7","N7","N8","N7","N5","N7","N7","N9","N7","N8","N7","N7","N4","N8","N7","N5","N9","N7","N4","N8","N7","N9","N4","N7","N4","N4","N7","N8","N5","N2","N4","N7","N8","N7","N5","N7","N7","N6","N7","N8","N9","N4","N7","N3","N8","N8","","N9","N7","N7","N8","N5","N5","N7","N8","N4","N7","N9","N7","N8","","N4","N7","N9","N8","N8","N4","N1","N4","N7","N5","N7","N4","N7","N7","","N8","N5","N7","N9","N4","N5","N4","N8","N9","N7","N7","N5","N8","N8","N7","N8","N4","N4","N7","N4","N4","N8","N4","N7","N4","","N7","N9","","N9","N9","","N9","N7","N7","N7","N6","N7","N4","N5","N7","N4","N5","N9","N2","N7","N8","N7","N4","N8","N5","N7","N4","N9","N7","","N7","N7","N5","N8","N7","N7","N4","N8","N7","N7","","N7","N5","N8","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N7","N9","N8","N7","N5","N8","N7","N6","N4","N7","N5","N8","N7","N9","N7","N7","N5","N7","N5","N9","N3","N7","N7","N6","N7","N8","N7","N8","N7","N8","N8","N5","N4","N5","N6","N5","N5","N7","N5","N8","N4","N7","N8","N8","N8","N7","N7","N9","N8","N4","N7","N7","N5","N7","N7","N7","N7","N9","N8","N8","N7","N7","","N8","N7","N9","N8","N7","N5","N7","N1","N7","N3","N7","N4","","N7","N8","N7","N8","N8","N7","N5","N7","N6","N7","N9","N3","N7","N5","N8","N4","N8","","N8","N8","N5","N8","N8","N8","N7","N7","N5","N6","N4","N7","N7","N7","N5","N5","N7","N5","N7","N5","N2","N5","N7","","N9","N5","N8","N5","N8","N6","N7","N5","N8","N7","N7","N7","N4","N5","N7","N7","N7","N5","N7","N7","N4","N7","N6","N7","N5","N7","N7","N4","N9","N7","N8","N7","N7","N6","N7","N7","N9","N7","N7","N5","N7","N9","N7","N8","N9")
    
    wage=c("2605","4931","11123","3750","6180","858,31","5092","9276","8611","4500","3693","11489","2896","2220","5000","5398","6923","3800","9615","3448","5568","675","2906","1255,67","4177","4300","4200","5389","2205","6600","5700","5400","2610","2679","2600","2893","3742","2605","4835","2700","7533","3764","3074","3499","4075","6613","12785","2050","3550","3687","2700","3075","2688","5385","3225","2231","3872","3385","4075","3500","6679","2720","2497","2822","2400","3900","3400","7600","4600","5735","5000","3605","2650","1246","2543","9903","6400","4604","6510","2315","6600","3900","4198","4100","4129","4080","3623","3117","4298","2650","4362","3332","10000","5080","5438","6830","2866","4395","2443","4311","4759","6917","2386","4289","3350","1905","2858","3100","5600","2000","2900","4000","6966","3432","23888","8606","1881","2258","4403","5923","2605","2341","2854","4670","5056","2491","8434","4000","4583","2330","6063","3924","1271,58","2164","2249","2657","2449","2800","3448","2379","6941","5768","3913","3977","4067","4000","2773","2956","2569","5532","2868","4488","6162","2727","4650","2614","6000","3392","2411","2403,20","3090","3002","2594","2896","2862,40","2777","2230","1935","4750","8532","2128","4300","3000","4164","2605","2892","8623","3100","2729","3850","3855","5160","5232","6213","4707","4300","2408","2343","2624","1894","3255","969,57","3291,54","2820","4322","2159","2000","2427","11615","5555","1323,94","2448","5200","2901","3904","9338","3881","3536","2504","5202","3098","2936","3962","4692","5676","2650","3511","2766","3018","1900","5230","4100","4806","2700","2686","2605","10860","2942","4900","2963","3581","6613","4800","5231","8150","2429","2371","2461","3247","2480","10626","5702","2476","2200","6750","2776","5600","3700","2775","2780","5555","11600","5154","3300","3466","3362","5509","3700","2319","2918","2912","11194","2610","5670","2605","4515","2000","8409","2945","2533","9629","3850","2127","6200","3719","12276","2159","3432","2350","2529","4500","7272","2798","2379","2718","4431","6410","3229","2350","3415","2700","3182","2800","5900","14373","2165","3417","2462","7029","6500","17696","8730","4500","2851","4710","3169","2380","3479","6492","2438","","8881","3000","5500","1230,49","2804","4427","8161","9576","4738","2026","699,37","2000","5166","2858","4100","2593","3647","3561","985,47","4699","2300","3230","10710","3700","3551","2209","5654","11539","3150","3600","2775","4939","5506","4235","6500","2291","2450","2835","2661","2457","5700","2000","3101","2374","1353,60","3650","11466","14200","12000","12650","985,47","6987","2768","3800","4406","2882","4760","1952","2577","2958","2289","2912","12924","1911","4100","5069","3600","1569","6891","1840","3278","1969","13077","2650","24577","3205","4165","2899","5006","2700","3612","2183","5366","3000","2950","26667","5699","3607","7292","3350","3213","4586","4838","5077","3908","10300","7398","3916","3373","7113","4150","3476","1935","3217","2660","6816","2928","6300","2912","3587","2390","4260","3264","20290","1255,68","2854","3800","2835","4296","6000","3000","6954","4090","5605","5689","2838","2567","3055","2821","2300","3052","4400","2636","5953","2028","3861","5847","6800","4517","4341","2605","9300","7403","2292","4011","3280","2736","4002","5009","4697","2714","8716","6179","7700","2935","4236","1255,68","5252","2768","8314","5000","4000","2843","4428","1351,04","5014","2612","3003","2291","20258","2800","5128","4900","6611","5150","3516","3135","4037","3440","4920","9051","2414","2610","2905","6000","2001","4473","1351,04","5266","6863","1877","6010","6900","4369","3697","3005","3382","3473","2353","3925","2809","4240","3255","2424","4349","2770","3385","2776","2057","2734","3604","1351,05","7338","2600","5698","2945","4725","2792","4356","2970","7041","4030","4600","4294","2511","2422","4931","4003","3100","2860","3300","3500","2780","5872","3041","3873","2871","3109","2943","2091","7219","3061,60","3374","4049","4943","2745","5540","4350","7670","2735","4650","2959","4620","9807","5460","4396","10770")

df <- data.frame(sex, age, time_passed, level, wage)
```

clean up the data ("NA" to NA, level as ordered factor, sex as factor, age and wage as numeric)

```r
df <- transform(df, 
    sex=factor(ifelse(sex=="NA", NA, sex)),
    age=as.numeric(age),
    time_passed=as.numeric(time_passed),
    level=factor(ifelse(level=="", NA, level), ordered = TRUE),
    wage=as.numeric(wage))
```

```r
# plot age across levels
plot(age ~ level, data=df)
```

[image]

```r
# ggplot2 boxplot split by sex
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=level, y=age, fill=sex)) +
  geom_boxplot() 
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

remove NA level (if you like):

```r
ggplot(df[!is.na(df$level),], aes(x=level, y=age, fill=sex)) +
  geom_boxplot() 
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

linear regression shows level as significant covariate; about 24% of the differences in age are explained by level; in particular level 7 shows a significantly lower age:

```r
lm(age ~ level, data=df)   |> summary()
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = age ~ level, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -18.800  -6.719  -0.800   5.726  24.833 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  41.3419     0.7348  56.265  < 2e-16 ***
#> level.L      11.7616     2.5937   4.535 7.11e-06 ***
#> level.Q       4.7339     2.3219   2.039 0.041951 *  
#> level.C       2.6905     2.3459   1.147 0.251923    
#> level^4       2.3339     2.3347   1.000 0.317912    
#> level^5       0.4910     2.3112   0.212 0.831837    
#> level^6      -3.3753     2.1027  -1.605 0.109031    
#> level^7      -6.9824     1.9284  -3.621 0.000321 ***
#> level^8       0.3998     1.5226   0.263 0.792967    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 8.907 on 542 degrees of freedom
#>   (17 observations deleted due to missingness)
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.2533, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2423 
#> F-statistic: 22.98 on 8 and 542 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

multiple regression with sex and level shows no significant effect of sex:

```r
lm(age ~ level + sex, data=df)   |> summary()
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = age ~ level + sex, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -18.8000  -6.6787  -0.8149   5.4894  24.6040 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  40.9619     0.8581  47.735  < 2e-16 ***
#> level.L      11.8518     2.5965   4.565  6.2e-06 ***
#> level.Q       4.4574     2.3447   1.901 0.057822 .  
#> level.C       2.5181     2.3550   1.069 0.285441    
#> level^4       2.5722     2.3517   1.094 0.274547    
#> level^5       0.5759     2.3138   0.249 0.803545    
#> level^6      -3.5393     2.1119  -1.676 0.094343 .  
#> level^7      -6.8517     1.9349  -3.541 0.000433 ***
#> level^8       0.2476     1.5333   0.161 0.871776    
#> sexH          0.6880     0.8018   0.858 0.391264    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 8.91 on 541 degrees of freedom
#>   (17 observations deleted due to missingness)
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.2543, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2419 
#> F-statistic:  20.5 on 9 and 541 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

an alternative test for correlation of ranked (ordinal) data is the Spearman rank test, e.g. with the pspearman package to establish whether there is a significant correlation:

```r
library(pspearman)
with(df, spearman.test(age, level))
#> Warning in spearman.test(age, level): Cannot compute exact p-values with ties
#> 
#>  Spearman's rank correlation rho
#> 
#> data:  age and level
#> S = 18494952, p-value = 5.789e-16
#> alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#>       rho 
#> 0.3366372
```